# Networking in a Distributed Kubernetes Cluster Over Tailscale

Tags: vpn, kubernetes

### Background

I have two nodes, Narvi and Orcams, which are part of a Tailnet. They are located in physically distinct and differing "real" subnets. They can communicate with each other using Tailscale DNS without any issues. `traceroute` demonstrates that the communication between these nodes occurs directly through the `tailscale0` interface, both ways.

I am attempting to set up a Kubernetes cluster using `kubeadm` with Narvi as the control-plane node and Orcams as a worker node. Here's the `kubeadm init` command I used on Narvi:

```bash
kubeadm init --cri-socket /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --control-plane-endpoint narvi.taileb1e1.ts.net --apiserver-advertise-address $(tailscale ip --4) --pod-network-cidr 10.25.0.0/16 --service-cidr 10.26.0.0/16 --upload-certs
```

### Issue

Post the Kubernetes setup, I am facing challenges with pod networking. While pods can communicate with other nodes using `ping` or `traceroute`, I am unable to ping the internal IP addresses within the pod network CIDR (`10.25.0.0/16`). Running `ip route get` confirms correct routing of `10.25.0.0` through the `tailscale0` network.

I have experimented with various CNI plugins including Weave Net, Calico, and Flannel. Irrespective, pod-to-pod communication via Pod CIDRs almost always fails. I have checked ip routes and `iptables` (and even for testing purposes completely turned off `iptables`). I have also checked my Tailscale ACL (Access Control) which allow for all communications.

The behavior I observe with my node, say in the case of a Calico network, is that my worker nodes can successfully join but Calico nodes start to terminate constantly. The logs of which (similar to Flannel or Weave Net) show occasional connection refused especially when internal pod IP is used. Overall, I am at a loss to find one single error that can be the root cause, but have a strong feeling these all go back to ip routing.

### Environment

- **Nodes:** Narvi (control-plane), Orcams (worker)
- **OS:** Ubuntu (on both nodes)
- **Network:** Tailscale (Tailnet)
- **Kubernetes Setup:** `kubeadm`
- **CNI Plugins Tested:** Weave Net, Calico, Flannel

### Questions

1. Are there known configurations or CNI plugins that work well with Tailscale for pod networking in a distributed Kubernetes setup? A blog post [here](https://readthedocs.vinczejanos.info/Blog/2023/04/21/install-kube-tailscale/) suggests Weave Net and Flannel (I have tested both).
2. How can I ensure seamless pod-to-pod communication across the nodes over Tailscale?
   I know the question is a bit generic but I need help in thinking than specific ways of dealing with code/admin.